# Force video frame to contain full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a video frame with which i want to be full screen width. I have tried with css but thought the frame contains full width, the area with which the video plays is not full with.

[image]

How do i make this contain the whole screen width?

Below is my html and css

```css
.videoTrainings {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background: #fbfbfb;
}
.videoTrainings video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoTrainings">
  <video autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="videos/tomprint.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
  </video>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: removing `.videoTrainings video Height` or making it `auto` will do the trick

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the height from your css `.videoTrainings video` would do the trick
reference @Rene van der Lende comment

```
.videoTrainings video {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```